# Moderator/Administrator Script for website (HTML)

Tags: html, scripting

G´Day,

So I am making this website out of basic HTML. I wanted to add a Moderator/Administrator script for it and was wondering if there was any way I could Create a script myself easily. (Keep in mind that I only took one Web Design class and im still in High School.)

I did have a look at [How can I design an efficient moderator system for comments?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114483/how-can-i-design-an-efficient-moderation-system-for-comments?newreg=afe85a04291c44bb888c21b35fd1efbc)
, however it didn't really help me much as it wasn´t describing HTML. I was thinking something along the lines of:

MOD @username /MOD
ADMIN @username /ADMIN
MANAGER @username /MANAGER

Etc.

Different Levels of admin will have different available command inputs, and each level of mod/admin will have a panel that they can access. Only Website developers will be able to admin people until I can get an option for Me (Owner Admin) to be able to access on my panel.

Comment: Please comment below here on why you down voted my question. It is considered extremely disrespectful to me when people do not give a reason for their downvote. If you have no reason for your downvote, Kindly remove it and carry on. Thanks.

Comment: Joseph, I did neither close vote nor downvote, but if the question wasn't already closed, I would vote for closing it with the predefined "needs more focus" reason. The issue with this post is, it does not contain a clear problem statement - there is no question in this question. I guess what you wanted to ask for is "where do I start", but ["Where to start"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start) questions are not a good fit for the Q&A format iof this site and not well received by the community.

Comment: ... if you had asked, however, "is it possible what I am trying by using purely HTML", that question might have been better received, but it could have left the impression of not having done enough research on your own before asking. Note he downvote button's tool tip starts with  "This question does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with HTML nor is it possible for web content running inside a browser to have any privileged access to the underlying operating system or device.

Running any kinds of computer instruction such as these requires a programming language capable of solving algorithmic problems.    HTML is merely a document mark-up format for describing the appearance and layout of web content, and not a programming language.

Furthermore, the security built-in to all modern web browsers intentionally prevents all but the most benign interaction with the underlying device or operating system because granting such access to something which may be loaded over a public internet connection would be highly abusable (And indeed the history of earlier web technologies is littered with examples of vulnerabilities which allowed malicious code to run on a user's computer merely as a consequence of them loading a webpage).

Answer (score 0):

> it didn't really help me much as it wasn´t describing HTML

This is (essentially) the answer to your question: you can't do this in HTML alone. You will need a backend system (Python, PHP, etc) to handle this and - practically - some JavaScript on the front-end. It would *in theory* be possible without the JavaScript, but the UX would be so clunky by modern standards it wouldn't be worth it.

Stepping back a bit, HTML is a markup language - it describes a document and how it should be presented; it is very deliberately not a general purpose programming language, so there is much you can't do in HTML.